# Delete special lines from the file in php

Tags: php

I have the php script as below, which has been created to modify inside of interfaces.conf file. When eth0 interface is dhcp, I need to make it static and create additional three lines for ip address gateway and subnetmask. When the eth0 is static, I need to change it to dhcp but I can not delete the next three lines which is created before for ip address, gateway and subnetmask above. can you help me to solve this problem?

```
<?php
$my_file = fopen("interfaces.conf","r") or die (" Unable to open file !");
$new_file = fopen("interfaces.txt","w") or die (" Unable to open file !");
$replaced = false;
while (!feof($my_file)){
    $line = fgets($my_file);
    if (stristr($line,'iface eth0 inet dhcp')) {
         $line = "iface eth0 inet static\n"."address"." "."192.168.42.1\n"."netmask"." "."255.255.255.0\n"."gateway"." "."192.168.42.0\n";
         $replaced = true;
    }
    elseif (stristr($line,'iface eth0 inet static')) {
         $line = "iface eth0 inet dhcp\n";
         $replaced = true;
    }
    fputs($new_file, $line);
}

fclose($my_file);
fclose($new_file);
if ($replaced){
    rename("interfaces.txt","interfaces.conf");
    }
else {
    unlink("interfaces.txt");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the actual result of the script as it is? It doesn't look that wrong what you did.

**EDIT 1:**

Quick solution would be to add sort of a "comment line" (or knowing the following line) to detect  which lines to "skip" and when to restart pushing them to the new file.

Other solution: I guess the lines you want to delete have a very specific "format". You can use regular expressions to find/replace the lines then ;)

**EDIT 2:**

One solution would by something like this:

```
<?php
$my_file = fopen("interfaces.conf","r") or die (" Unable to open file !");
$new_file = fopen("interfaces.txt","w") or die (" Unable to open file !");
$replaced = false;
$lock = 0;
while (!feof($my_file)){
    $line = fgets($my_file);
    if (stristr($line,'iface eth0 inet dhcp')) {
        $line = "iface eth0 inet static\n"."address"." "."192.168.42.1\n"."netmask"."   "."255.255.255.0\n"."gateway"." "."192.168.42.0\n";
        $replaced = true;
    } elseif (stristr($line,'iface eth0 inet static')) {
        $line = "iface eth0 inet dhcp\n";
        fputs($new_file, $line); // replace this line 
        $lock = 3; // and lock the next 3 lines from being copied to the new file
        $replaced = true;
    }
    if($lock != 0) {
      $lock--;
    } else {
      fputs($new_file, $line);
    }
}

fclose($my_file);
fclose($new_file);
if ($replaced){
    rename("interfaces.txt","interfaces.conf");
}
else {
unlink("interfaces.txt");
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a comment.

Comment: Cannot comment while I don't have enough reputation - sorry.

Comment: the lines which are created for ip address, subnetmask and gateway are saved inside the file, when I move from static to dhcp. However, when I move from static to dhcp, those lines should be removed.

Comment: @user3840698 Ah okay - I got it. I updated my answer ;)

Comment: ..."answers" are not answers. The text from my comment was inserted from the low-quality answer review queue tool.  It's a boilerplate explanation created by the moderators addressing the fact that "answers" need to be answers.  In all likelihood, this one will get deleted if it's not updated to be a solid answer soon.

Comment: I need to delete the next three lines after eht0 inet static line. I will be happy if you provide solution in php code

Comment: @user3840698 I've added some code right now. Maybe this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, for this response and it is working as I expected :) Can you explain little bit how it works? Thanks again :)

Comment: Nice to hear that it was helpful. You may consider marking the answer as correct then.

Basically I added a variable `$lock` that locks the next "x" lines from being copied into the new file. The added "if" construct only copies the line when `$lock` is zero. If it is larger nothing is copied and $lock is reduced by one. So setting `$lock = 3` means that for the next 3 lines of the file `$lock` will be decremented instead of copying the line. After the 3 lines `$lock` is zero again and it continues copying the next lines. So this also works if you have the same construct twice in your file.